# Remove folder from magento URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, url, mod-rewrite

I have Magento store installed in folder called magento and it is working fine and i managed to remove the index.php using .htaccess

Now the URL for my store is

> www.example.com/magento/

I don't want to move my files to the root directory but i need to remove /magento from the URL and i think the only way will be using the .htaccess but i can't understand it clearly.

I did find some links but every one have another situation and because my weak knowledge of the .htaccess file it didn't help me.

What i need simply

> www.example.com/magento/

to

> www.example.com

Can someone can guide me how to rewrite the URL ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule !^magento/ /magento%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Same issue the link redirected to www.example.com/magento

Comment: working after changing the base URL from magento backend but now i can't log in to the backend

Comment: actually let me add a condition for admin

Comment: Try it now. You will still access admin as `/magento/admin/`

Comment: Actually first time to log to admin backend it remove the store and give me 404 not found, then i add the store to the link then it works

Comment: after making some tests i think what i need to fix the backend issue is to rewrite /index.php/admin/ to /magento/index.php/admin/ 
Can you please help me with this one ? thanks a million for your support

Comment: Sure I can add that rule. I am away from my computer. I will add that rule in few hours.

Comment: it give me internal server error when i update the .htaccess with the new rule, the thing is when i hover any link in the backend it show www.example.com/index.php/admin/..etc the but the backend accessable with /magento or without /index.php .. i noticed i have .htaccess within the magento directory with rule for index.php

Comment: With this rule in place are you able to access magento admin using `www.example.com/magento/index.php/admin/` URL?

Comment: Also I believe above rule is in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`

Comment: the above rules in the root directory i can access the backend from this link www.example.com/magento/index.php/admin but everything inside the backend take me to /index.php/admin without the /magento .. i have another .htaccess inside the magento directory with the following rule RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: Yes I know about that rule in `/magento/.htaccess`. I have updated above code slightly, see if that helps. If that doesn't work I will try it on a host tomorrow where I have `magento` installed.

Comment: not working also , i think there is a work around with the admin url or admin path in the backend configuration->admin , Thanks for your support engineer anubhava

Comment: Oh alright, please give me time till tomorrow to investigate on my `magento host` and update accordingly.

Comment: ok thank anubhava very much, btw i changed the base url to www.example.com, should i change it back to www.example.com/magento and the htaccess rewrite will fix it ?

Comment: Problem solved ! , Thank you anubhava .. the solution simply is your .htaccess rules then use www.example.com/magento/ in the admin url inside the configuration->admin .. thanks for your support

Comment: Oh that is perfect, I am really glad it worked out :)